# What does $K(A)$ mean in field theory?

Tags: field-theory, notation

So in my notes it says that if $K\subset L$ is a field extension and $A \subset L$ is a subset then $K(A)$ is a subfield of $L$ containing both $K$ and $A$. It is in fact the smallest such subfield. I haven't fully grapsed the proof of this fact yet but I want to work a little more with this idea before revisiting the proof.

Now I am just unsure on how to actually generate such things in examples take purely for example the extension $\Bbb{Q} \subset \Bbb{C}$ and the subset $\{i,\pi\} \subset \Bbb{C}$ then this would mean that $\Bbb{Q}(i,\pi)$ is the smallest subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ containing both $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\{i, \pi\}$ correct?

What do the elements of $\Bbb{Q}(i,\pi)=\{\Bbb{Q},i,\pi\}$ look like? Would we simply just take all the different combinations of $\{\Bbb{Q},i,\pi\}$ we can form and then use the operations from $\Bbb{C}$ so it would be
$\Bbb{Q}(i,\pi)=\{a+b\pi+ci+di\pi : a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{Q}\}$ and similarly would $\Bbb{Q}(i,\pi, e)$ just be all the different ways you can choose the elements to go after a rational coefficient $i,i\pi,ie,e\pi,e\pi i...$ and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is $\pi^2$ is your description of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\pi)$? A field should be closed under multiplication.

Comment: So would it be $\Bbb{Q}(i,\pi)=\{a+b\pi+ci+di\pi+e\pi^2 : a,b,c,d,e \in \Bbb{Q}\}$

Comment: ...and now what about $\pi^3$? Don't try to go as fast as possible, settle down and think.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi .. not to mention $\frac{17+\pi}{3-\pi}$

Comment: To put your instructor’s definition on a slightly firmer footing, let’s say this: consider the collection of all subfields of $L$ containing both $K$ and $A$. Then $K(A)$ is the intersection of all these fields. One needs to show that this is the same as Hagen von Eitzen’s constructive definition below, but the task is not hard.

Answer (score 2):

Each element of $K(A)$ can be written as a rational expression in the elements of $A$, i.e., for each $\alpha\in K(A)$, there are polynomials $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ with coefficients in $K$  and a finite pick of elements $a_1,\ldots,a_nb\in A$ such that $\alpha=\frac{f(a_1,\ldots,a_n} {g(a_1,\ldots,a_n}$.

It is clear that any such expression (with non-zero denominator) must be in every field containing $K$ and $A$. On the other hand, such expressions form a field, hence they form the smallest field as desired.

If all elements of $A$ are *algebraic*, we even have $K(A)=K[A]$, i.e., each element can be written as $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.